# How can I indexing sitemap my website?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, xml-sitemap

I want to optimize the sitelink on my website through the search console / webmaster

I want when searching on Google that appears are certain menus. for example menus, a, menu b and menu c

I am looking for some references. that we can set through the search console, only it requires a sitemap.xml that crawls first

so I accessed this https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/. I input my domain and click the start button. after the process is complete, i downloaded the xml sitemap file

my question is whether I directly upload the xml file to my hosting? or I need to edit it first to set what menus appear when typing keywords on google?

Update :

My xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://www.mywebsite.com/</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-10-13T23:46:01+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
...
<url>
  <loc>https://www.mywebsite.com/menu-a</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-10-13T23:46:01+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
...
<url>
  <loc>https://www.mywebsite.com/menu-b</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-10-13T23:46:01+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.64</priority>
</url>


</urlset>
```

there are 2000 lines of code, but here I only get a few

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether I directly upload the xml file to my hosting?
>   or I need to edit it first to set what menus appear when typing
>   keywords on google?

We need to clear some things up before we get into the rest.

Sitemaps have nothing to do with Google Sitelinks. You do not have to have a sitemap to have Sitelinks. Sitemaps are completely optional and generally advisable only for larger sites or sites with a login or paywall.

Some SEOs advise that a site have a sitemap to encourage Sitelinks. However, I have had several smaller sites with Sitelinks without a sitemap. You can certainly cover-your-bases by creating one just-in-case.

You cannot define how the Sitelinks appear for your site. You cannot influence Sitelinks with a sitemap. There is nothing to define within the sitemap after you create one using https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/. The sitemap only lists resources upon your site using XML.

You will need to be able to up-load your sitemap to your site. You would up-load the sitemap to your home directory using the name of sitemap.xml. You can use another name, however, I would advise against it for now. Your sitemap should be available by accessing your site as www.example.com/sitemap.xml.

https://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_location

How you up-load your sitemap depends upon your web host. If you have FTP (file transfer protocol), you can use that. If you have a control panel, you will likely be able to up-load your file using the control panel interface. This is likely the easiest way especially if you are not familiar with FTP.

You will want to create a Google Search Console account. You will want to submit your sitemap to Google using the Search Console.

https://search.google.com/search-console/about

To read about encouraging Sitelinks, you can read this. https://bloggingwizard.com/google-sitelinks/ There are other pages of course, this just happens to be the first one I found and it seems fairly detailed and easy to understand.

Comment: Great thanks. But if I read here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739898/html-how-to-get-my-subpages-listed-on-a-google-search, it seems we can control the menus that want to be displayed

Comment: @SuccessMan No you can't. The old version of Search Console would allow you to remove a Sitelink - that's it. Google chooses to show Sitelinks based upon your navigation and those pages that seem to be popular and only one click from the home page. You may want to place your navigation in a div tag with the id of nav or use the nav tag. Cheers!!

Comment: So are you saying that the new version of Search Console doesn't allow us to set it up anymore? I only read from the references in the link

Comment: @SuccessMan You can submit a sitemap. The old version of Search Console would allow a site owner to remove a link from Googles Sitelinks, however, I do not see the same option anymore.

Comment: I will check it first to be sure